# lodash - group and populate arrays using typescript

Tags: typescript, lodash

Using lodash, how could I group the company_name  that have the same main_role_group_id as seen below?

I wrote this out using nested for loops but was thinking there would be a more elegant way of doing this in lodash. I haven't used it much and trying to figure out which function to use.

```
[{ 
    "main_role_group_id": 5,
    "company_name": "Fitzsimons PTY LTD"
},
{
    "main_role_group_id": 1,
    "company_name": "APF Brisbane Pty Ltd"
},
{
    "main_role_group_id": 5,
    "company_name": "Five Islands Secondary College"
},
{
    "main_role_group_id": 1,
    "company_name": "General Excavators Pty Ltd"
},
{
    "main_role_group_id": 7,
    "company_name": "Chubb Security - SA Office"
},
{
    "main_role_group_id": 7,
    "company_name": "Stay Kool Airconditioning & Electrical Services"
}]
```

to

```
[{ 
    "main_role_group_id": 5,
    "company": [{"company_name": "Fitzsimons PTY LTD"},{"company_name": "Five Islands Secondary College"}]
},
{
    "main_role_group_id": 1,
    "company": [{"company_name": "APF Brisbane Pty Ltd"},{"company_name": "General Excavators Pty Ltd"}]
},
{
    "main_role_group_id": 7,
    "company": [{"company_name": "Chubb Security - SA Office"},{"company_name": "Stay Kool Airconditioning & Electrical Services"}]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

lets your nested array as `companies`

```
var groupVal = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(companies, 'main_role_group_id'), clist = clist.map(company => _.omit(company, 'main_role_group_id')));

console.log(groupVal);
```